# Run python script in interactive mode

Tags: python-2.7, windows-8, menu, interactive

With a previous install of Python 2.7 on a Windows 7 machine I could start a script by right-clicking on the filename in windows explorer. Ther was a menu option "Run in interactive mode". By clicking that, a screen would open up, the script would run and.... it would stay open to inspect the output on the screen and do some further actions.

In a fresh install on a Windows 8 machine, this menu option is not present. I can dubble click or Open the file, but then the window closes after running the script.

How can I create the menu entry "Run in interactive mode" when right-clicking on a py file in Windows 8?

I could not find answers in this site or on the Python site.

Comment: I'd appreciate this, too! Not necessarily the menu entry - any possibility would be interesting, to stop inside a script without releasing the variables from memory, so that I can examine them

Answer (score 6):

What you need to do is to add "-i" option when run a python file.

```
C:\windows\system32>python -i main.py
```

Then you will go into the interactive mode, where you can print current variables, call functions and so on.

To make it as a right menu, you can add following cotent to Windows Registery.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Run in interactive mode]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Run in interactive mode\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\python.exe\" \"-i\" \"%1\" %*"
```